# Stochastic recovery rates

Tags: credit

How do I model the randomness of recovery rate given default when pricing credit derivatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard reference is Anderson and Sidenius [Extensions to the Gaussian Copula: Random recovery and random factor loadings](http://www.defaultrisk.com/pa_model_15.htm). Random recovery proved necessary in 2007/2008 when you couldn't calibration standard one factor base correlation models. [This paper](http://www.defaultrisk.com/pp_recov_45.htm) discusses this, and might be an easier starting point than the Anderson and Sidenius paper.

Comment: Are they still needed? do we use them for anything else than credit tranches?

Comment: Not sure if it's still needed. I've not done credit in a while.

Comment: What do you think about the Krekel model?

Answer (score 2):

CreditMetrics uses monte carlo simulation assuming a beta-distribution fitted to historical recovery rates.

Comment: What about CDOs?

Comment: Also, how do people take into account the correlation of recovery rates and other factors (default times), and go from historical data to the risk-neutral world (if at all)?

Comment: Sorry, thats beyond my scope, but maybe someone else has an answer.